# How do i re-write this gulpfile.js in gulp version 4.0

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-modules, clasp

My goal is to automatically push files when edited with the help of gulp by executing "clasp push" on the terminal on my behalf.

I got this error when I wrote the following in gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const exec = require("child_process");

gulp.task('push', function () {
    exec("clasp push")
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch([
        '**/* .js',
        "**/* .html"
    ], ['push'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

The Error:

```
Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/gulpfile.js:15:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Then I realized I am using Gulp Version 4.0.0

Then I changed the code to the one below: compatible with Gulp V 4.0.0

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const exec = require("child_process");

gulp.task('push', gulp.series('', function(){
    exec("clasp push")
}));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('push',function () {
    gulp.watch([
        '**/* .js',
        "**/* .html"
    ])
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch([
        '**/* .js',
        "**/* .html"
    ]);
}));
```

But then I still got this error:

> assert.js:350
>           throw err;
>           ^
>
> ```
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: 
>     at getFunction (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/normalizeArgs.js:15:5)
>     at map (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/node_modules/arr-map/index.js:20:14)
>     at normalizeArgs (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/normalizeArgs.js:22:10)
>     at Gulp.series (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/node_modules/undertaker/lib/series.js:13:14)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/micklo/Desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptAppName/gulpfile.js:4:24)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
> ```

**What am i doing wrong?**

Some info:

> OS: Mac Os (Mojave)
>
> Gulp Versions -> CLI version: 2.1.0, Local version: 4.0.0
>
> Node: v10.15.3
>
> Clasp: 2.1.0

Comment: `clasp push --watch`? I do admit that you must execute that at the start of your dev session, and then exit it at the end, but it in theory is otherwise precisely what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix to that particular error is that you have called `gulp.series` on an empty/non-existant task in your `push` task. `gulp.series` is expecting either a list of strings corresponding to tasks you've declared (such as `push`, `watch`, and `default`) or task functions.

Getting rid of the the `''` task in the series will fix it:

```
gulp.task('push', gulp.series(function(){
    exec('clasp push')
}));
```

However you now have some other problems:

1. None of your tasks have callbacks. Each Gulp task is asynchronous so you either have to use callbacks or `return` a stream/promise/event emitter/child process/observable (examples of which are [located in the docs here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion)). As an example:

```
gulp.task('push', function(done){
    exec('clasp push', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        done(err);
      });
});
```

2. You're not passing in a function or series/parallel sequence to `gulp.watch` so it's not doing anything. If you're trying to run the `push` task whenever any `.js` or `.html` files are changed, you will want to change it to:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(done) {
    gulp.watch([
        '**/*.js',
        '**/*.html'
    ], gulp.series('push'));
    done();
});
```

3. Your glob patterns have an extra space in the watch command before the file extension: `'**/*.js'` instead of  `'**/* .js'`
4. You likely want `require("child_process").exec` (with the extra `.exec` tagged on) to allow you to execute shell commands using an `exec(command)` syntax.
5. You don't need to repeat the `watch` command when calling it in the `default` task:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('push', 'watch'));
```

6. You can remove a lot of the `gulp.series` calls to remove the `<anonymous>` task calls and simplify the tasks. Each task only needs one function and you should probably aim to use `gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel` with sets of named tasks.

Changing those points, the code should look something like:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('push', function(done){
    exec('clasp push', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        done(err);
      });
});

gulp.task('watch', function(done) {
    gulp.watch([
        '**/*.js',
        '**/*.html'
    ], gulp.series('push'));
    done();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('push', 'watch'));
```

You can rewrite this using the gulp v4 recommended pattern of exporting tasks:

```
const { series, watch } = require('gulp');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function push(done) {
    exec('clasp push', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        done(err);
      });
}

function watchPush() {
    return watch(['**/*.js', '**/*.html'], push);
}

exports.push = push;
exports.default = exports.watch = series(push, watchPush);
```

Comment: i got the following error "[09:39:39] The following tasks did not complete: default, watch, push, <anonymous>
[09:39:39] Did you forget to signal async completion?"

Comment: It might be that the `exec` function needs to signal the gulp task callback in its own callback function. I've changed the final code block in the answer to reflect this. 

If that's not it, I would double check that the gulp version you're running on the command line is 4.0.0 with `gulp --version` (as you might have a global gulp@4.0.0 install and a local gulp@3.*.* install).

Comment: @Micklo_Nerd I've also simplified some of the tasks by removing some `gulp.series` calls and added in a rewrite using the gulp v4 recommended exporting tasks pattern which might give you some better luck.
If the error still persists, does it persist when you call `gulp push` or just when you call `gulp`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   For re-write this gulpfile.js in gulp version 4.0 Please updated your 
   gulpfile.js according to your requirement. 

   this solution for assert.js:350 throw err; Bootstarp 4, SASS, gulp 4.
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    var gulp        = require('gulp');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

    // Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
    gulp.task('sass', function() {
        return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 
        'src/scss/*.scss'])
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });

    // Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
    gulp.task('js', function() {
        return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
         'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 
         'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });

    // Static Server + watching scss/html files
    gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function() {

        browserSync.init({
            server: "./src"  
        });

        gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 
         'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
        gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    }));

    gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('js','serve'));
```